# Organizing values column output in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe and I would like to pivot the data into a specific wide format. This is the input data format:

```
data = {'DUT': [1,1,1,1],
    'TEMP': [25,25,25,25],
    'FREQ':[100,200,100,200],
    'LEVEL':[0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2],
    'RESULT1':[1.011,2.011,1.021,2.021],
    'RESULT2':[1.012,2.012,1.022,2.022]
    }

df = DataFrame(data,columns= ['DUT', 'TEMP', 'FREQ', 'LEVEL', 'RESULT1', 'RESULT2'])
```

print df looks like this (sorry, i dont know how to add interpreter output directly):

```
 DUT  TEMP  FREQ  LEVEL  RESULT1  RESULT2

 1    25   100    0.1    1.011    1.012

 1    25   200    0.1    2.011    2.012

 1    25   100    0.2    1.021    1.022

 1    25   200    0.2    2.021    2.022
```

This is the code I have tried so far, which is close but not exactly what I need:

```
unstack_data = df.pivot_table(values=['RESULT1','RESULT2'], index=['DUT','TEMP'], columns=['LEVEL','FREQ'], aggfunc='mean')
```

[Result output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ZvN.png)

The data is grouped by the values columns `RESULT1` and `RESULT2` on the very top line of the df output. However, i would like `RESULT1` and `RESULT2` to be ungrouped like this, sorry I don't seem to be able to post images directly:

[Required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaGNu.png)

Is this possible using python and pandas? Thanks

Comment: Did you try `df.pivot_table(index='DUT', columns=['LEVEL', 'FREQ', 'TEMP'])`?

Comment: Thanks Erfan, I just tried that but it still gives me the same top level grouping of RESULT1 and RESULT2 as i was getting.